# yii2 Getting unknown property: common\models\User::password_hash

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i'm making backend login page in yii2 to my database in mysql. in my database i have table "konto" with columns: "username" and "password". i'm using default yii2 functions, but i'm still getting "Getting unknown property: common\models\User::password_hash" when i'm trying to log in.

what i understand is that the function in backend/common/models/User.php

```
 public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
    }
```

is probably wrong. i have found similar question and tried to change it to

```
public function validatePassword($password)
{
    return $this->password === Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash ($password);
}
```

but then i get error username or password message. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: users table must have auth_key, password_hash and password_reset_token. so you have to add these columns in konto table.

Answer (score 2):

No need to add column in konto table.
Please add public $password_hash in your model file just like below.

```
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public $password_hash;

    .....
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yii required some additional columns. so must add those columns to your konto table.

```
'auth_key',
'password_hash,
'password_reset_token',
```

Yii will generate password hash, while saving new record.
auth_key will useful for REST API services and password_reset_token is useful for reset the forgot password.

I hope, you got the answer.